# Как работает HttpContext.Response.HasStarted?

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-core

Вроде понятно как происходить последовательность обработки запроса в ASP .NET Core.
Но натолкнулся на свойство `HttpContext.Response.HasStarted`, которое заставляет задуматься.
[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68357686/whats-httpcontext-response-hasstarted-for) был вопрос зачем оно нужно, где есть ссылки на документацию, но контекст не полностью раскрыт.

Если разбиение ответа на отправку заголовков и тела происходит в коде middleware/run, то интересно как такое реализовать своими руками (привык к одной целостной отправки ответа). Можно пример такого использования? Подозреваю что это нужно для возможности начать отправлять часть данных раньше и по результату быстрее закончить суммарное время ответа.

Если процесс разбиения вызывается не на уровне кода middleware/run, а на уровне ниже (либ дотнета/протоколов), то опасная возможность, которая может преподнести много сюрпризов таких как не возможность дописать хедеры в каком-то middleware, хотя они нужны были.

Как этот процесс работает?

Comment: Какое еще разбиение?  Когда наступает момент, что нужно отправить первый байт тела ответа, то сначала посылаются хидеры. И далее хидеры бесполезно модифицировать, ведь они "уже ушли". Флаг `HasStarted` и говорит об этом.

Comment: "Gets a value indicating whether response headers have been sent to the client." https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.hasstarted?view=aspnetcore-5.0   Как тогда понимать что хедеры отправлены? Отправлено ли тело в таком случае? Это не разбиение?

Comment: Клиент держит коннект с сервером и ждет ответа. И для клиента и для сервера это представлено как поток (Stream), в который сервер пишет, а клиент читает. http протокол требует, чтобы сначала шли хедеры. Перед тем как начать писать в этот stream тело ответа - система первым делом пишет в этот stream словарь хедеров и ставит флаг. (Тут модифицировать хедеры уже поздно - они записаны в выходной поток (пусть даже все повисло в буфере потока)). А потом начинает писать туда тело ответа (готового или частичного). Это не разбиение, а "дозапись".

Comment: Можно создать ответ, и он будет лучшим. Только хотелось бы знать откуда информация - дока/дебаг/...

Comment: "откуда информация" - а по другому такое и не сделать.  Для потока нет понятия "хедер" и "данные" - для него все "просто набор байтов, которые пишутся в поток". Отправляющая сторона просто пишет в поток данные в нужном порядке и по мере наличия этих данных. И так в любом языке и потоке ввода-вывода (сеть, файлы и т.д.)